# Can't get length of array? (not querying for property)

Tags: solidity, arrays

```
mapping(uint256 => address) public userList;

function getUserCount() public constant returns(uint userCount) {
 return userList.length;
}

function newUser(address _address) internal returns(bool success) {
    userList.push(_address);
    return true;
  }

function getUser(uint256 _userId) public constant returns(address){
      return(userList[_userId]);
  }
```

throws error "member length can not be found" - can somebody explain to me why this doesn't work? i've looked at the storage patterns list and saw that they would add an additional array to have a user count - i was really trying to avoid that so that on high demand two users would not get the same id, by setting their id to length - was just planning to push the new users without setting an id manually

Answer (score 3):

In the code above `userList` is not an array, it is a mapping. Mapping's do not have a `length` property because we can't know what the size of a mapping is.

If you convert `mapping(uint256 => address) public userList;` to `address[] public userList;` then it should work as expected.

Also, regarding your last point. It's fine for you to use `userList.length` to determine a user's ID, even if two users are added in the same block/at the same time, as the transactions are processed sequentially, so they will still get different ID's.

Comment: okay, i think i'm not really getting the concept of arrays in solidity quite yet

how would i declare mapping(address => mapping (uint256 => EntityStruct)) as a proper array?

Comment: Mappings and Arrays are fundamentally different data structures. I'm pretty sure you can't represent that Mapping within a Mapping, with those types, as an Array. However, you could represent `mapping(uint256 => mapping (uint256 => EntityStruct))` as an Array with `EntityStruct[][]`.